# Hello world in Prolog

Tags: prolog, read-eval-print-loop

I'm tearing my hair out trying to find how to just write a Hello World program in Prolog.  I just want to create a program that runs like so:

```
> ./hw
Hello, world!
>
```

The problem is that every single example I can find works in a REPL, like so:

```
?- consult(hello_world).
% hello compiled 0.00 sec, 612 bytes

Yes
?- hello_world.
Hello World!

Yes
```

This is the same even with examples of compiled Prolog: the program still just drops into a REPL.  This is obviously not much use for a "general-purpose" language.  So, how do I write the traditional Hello World?

Comment: Where are your virtues of declarative programming now? MWHAHAHA :)

Comment: I dunno, I think most *real* implementations of Prolog in an application use it as an embedded language for what it's good at, rather than write the entire app (UI, file I/O, hardware control, etc...) in Prolog.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/):

`$ cat hello.pl 
:- initialization(main).
main :- write('Hello World!'), nl, halt.`

$ gplc hello.pl 
$ ./hello
Hello World!

Comment: FYI, Same in [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=initialization/1)

Answer (score 11):

You can write your source file to both launch the Prolog interpreter and to quit it when your code is done running. Here is an example using SWI-Prolog:

```
#!/usr/bin/swipl -q -t hello_world -f

hello_world :- write('Hello World'), nl, 
               halt.
```

Assuming you put this in a file named 'hw', and set the executable permission, you can call it like you want to:

```
$ ./hw
Hello World
$
```

Comment: I notice that `write(3 + 1)` prints `3 + 1` instead of `4`. Is there some way to print the output of arithmetic expressions like this one?

Answer (score 4):

Prolog is not really a *general purpose* language. We use it to design artificial intelligence systems at university.

You'd have to define a fact, that answers "hello world".

```
hello('hello world').
```

Then, inquire the fact:

```
?- hello(X).
```

However, depending on the PROLOG compiler, you probably have a `write()` rule, that you could use:

```
?- write('hello world'), nl.
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It's just another explanation how to run it in REPL. This is exactly the opposite of what the OP wanted to know. Moreover, the OP has explicitly stated that he is frustrated exactly about the fact that there is a million of explanations of how to run it in REPL, but no explanations of how to make it do exactly what one wants it to do, namely printing a single string.

Answer (score 1):

```
writeln('hello world').
```